# How to adapt Bundt cake recipes to other size Bundt pans?

Tags: cake, pan, conversion

I just impulse-purchased a couple of adorable Bundt pans that are 6" in diameter. Since this is not a standard size, how should I adapt recipes intended for other size Bundt pans? (Google tells me 10" is considered standard.) How do I calculate, or at least approximate, the appropriate quantity of batter, temperature, and bake time?

(The pans I purchased have a pale nonstick coating.)

Thanks for your insights, bakers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity of batter is the easiest thing to figure out. Take one large measuring cup, fill it with a known quantity of water, and pour into the tin. Once it's full, subtract the amount of water left in the measuring cup to get the volume of liquid that fits in the tin.

Alternatively, weigh the tin, fill it with water and weigh again. Then take advantage of the fact that 1 litre of water weighs exactly 1 kg to figure out the volume of water that fits in the tin.

As for time and temperature, that comes down to the precise recipe. In general, smaller baked goods bake at slightly higher temperatures than larger, so I would start by increasing the recipe temperature by 15-20 or so degrees Celsius. As for time, I would personally just keep a close eye on the cakes and start checking for doneness (with an instant read thermometer or a cake stick) after half the time for the original recipe.